# Editar elemento padre del que se ha hecho clic

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5

Saludos,

En esta tabla hago un select y en uno de los "TD" he hecho un INPUT para rellenar ese espacio con los datos que se desee, todo con AJAX y funcionando perfectamente, pero ese hago un INSERT del INPUT me sigue saliendo la casilla del INPUT y quisiera canviarla por el valor nuevo que he introducido. Creo que una solución sería poder seleccionar al padre del elemento clicado y cambiar su HTML pero no se como hacerlo.

Dejo el código aquí.

```
                               <?php
                            while ($result = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['id_order'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['num_factura'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['num_albaran'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['reference'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['customer'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['email'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['dni'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['group_name'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['BI'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['total_paid_real'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['RE'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['payment'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $result['date_add'] ?></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        if ($result['utm_source'] != NULL || $result['utm_source'] != "") {
                                            echo $result['utm_source'];
                                        } else {
                                            ?>
                                                <div style="width: 100px;">
                                                    <!--<form name="utm" action="" onSubmit="enviarDatosUTM(); return false" >
                                                        <input type="number" name="id_order" id="id_order" value="<?php echo $result['id_order'] ?>" style="display: none;" />
                                                        <input type="text" size="5px" name="utm_source" id="utm_source"/>
                                                        <input type="submit" value="&#10004;"/>
                                                    </form>-->
                                                    <input type="number" name="id_order" id="id_order" value="<?php echo $result['id_order'] ?>" style="display: none;"/>
                                                    <input type="text" size="5px" name="utm_source" id="utm_source" />
                                                    <input type="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="enviarDatosUTM($('#id_order').val(), $('#utm_source').val());
                                                                    return false;" value="&#10004;"/>
                                                           <?php
                                                   }
                                                   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El modo de obtener el elemento padre a través de otro es:

```
$("#elemento").closest("td");
```

Ahora, si deseas hacerle algo a ese elemento, como cambiar el html sería algo así:

```
$("#elemento").closest("td").html('<input value="nuevoValor">');
```

Saludos.
Acá dejo la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)